# Byte array to a number

Tags: arrays

I have a byte array of 6 elements which contains the MAC address of a WiFi chip. How do I convert this into a single value. For e.g. If the array is:

```
mac[0] = 208 
mac[1] = 181
mac[2] = 194
mac[3] = 193
mac[4] = 114
mac[5] = 219
```

How do I get a value like this: 208181194193114219 which in representation is essentially all the digits concatenated.

I tried AND'ing the individual mac IDs with 0xFFh and then bit-shifted them to the left but I see a value of `3250763216`. This is the code:

```
uint32_t deviceID = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   deviceID += (mac[i] & 0xFFh) << (8 * i);
}
Serial.print("Device ID : "); Serial.println(deviceID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;


    int mac[] = {208,181,194,193,114,219};

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof mac / sizeof mac[0]; ++i)
        ss << mac [i];

    int result;
    ss >> result;
    std::cout << result; //208181194193114219
}
```

Comment: I need to know how to do this in C++.

Comment: sorry,check answer again.